# Xamarin: Use NuGet FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am totally new to Xamarin, and now want to use vectorgrahpics in my xamarin.forms application.
In order to do so, I right clicked on the Solution > Mange NuGet Packages for Solution > Install Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms

Then I used this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Class="SMSIP_Xamarin.FileBrowser"
             Title="File Browser">
    <ListView x:Name="listView" RowHeight="60" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View >
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="8,8,8,8">
                            <ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" Source="{Binding IconSource}"/>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                                <Label Text="{Binding FileName}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,0,0,-5" FontSize="18" TextColor="Black"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Size}" FontSize="12" TextColor="Gray" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <Switch IsToggled="{Binding DoSynchronization}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

No I get the error

> "ffimageloadingsvg" is an undeclared prefix.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a namespace declaration for ffimageloadingsvg on the top of the page:

```
xmlns:ffimageloadingsvg="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms"
```

So it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:ffimageloadingsvg="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms"
             x:Class="SMSIP_Xamarin.FileBrowser"
             Title="File Browser">
    <ListView x:Name="listView" RowHeight="60" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View >
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="8,8,8,8">
                            <ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" Source="{Binding IconSource}"/>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                                <Label Text="{Binding FileName}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,0,0,-5" FontSize="18" TextColor="Black"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Size}" FontSize="12" TextColor="Gray" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <Switch IsToggled="{Binding DoSynchronization}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, can you answer me a small follow up question: Where do I find the correct namespae to set, so why exactly ffimageloadingsvg="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms" ?

Comment: Most packages specify it in their documentation https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/SVG-support - But its the assembly name of the referenced assembly and the namespace that the control you need resides in.